# quotient and remainder without division and modulo operators

Tags: java

I've been working on this problem for the past two hours or so and I've encountered a roadblock. I can actually perform the division but when it comes time to print the remainder that isn't 0 the output doesn't match. I would like to know what is it what I'm doing wrong.

```
public class Division {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int numerator = 0;
      int numeratorprint = 0;       
      int denominator = 0;
      int product = 0;
      int remainder = 0;
      int counter = 1;

      Scanner input;
      input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter two positive intergers for division:\n");
      numerator = input.nextInt();
      numeratorprint = numerator;
      denominator = input.nextInt();

      while ((numerator < 0) || (denominator < 0)) {
         System.out.print("Enter two positive intergers for division:\n");
         numerator = input.nextInt();
         denominator = input.nextInt();
      }
      if (numerator == 0){
      System.out.print(numerator + "/" + denominator + " = " + numerator + " with a remainder of " + numerator);
      }
      else if (denominator == 0){
          System.out.print("This result is undefined (Cannot divide by Zero)");
      }
      else if (denominator > numerator){
        System.out.print("Cannot do proper fractions");
      }
      else {
         while (numerator > denominator){
              counter++;
              numerator = numerator - denominator;
              }
      }
      product = counter * denominator;
      remainder = numeratorprint - product;
      System.out.println(numeratorprint + " / " + denominator + " = " + counter + " with a remainder of " + remainder);
   }
}

/* Sample I/O 1 
Enter two positive intergers for division:
25
5
OUTPUT:
25 / 5 = 5 with a remainder of 0

Sample I/O 2
Enter two positive intergers for division:
27
5
OUTPUT: 
27 / 5 = 6 with a remainder of -3
*/
```

Comment: Note that if the numerator is smaller than the denominator that is when it's a proper fraction. Improper fractions are the other way around.

Comment: Thanks!, corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have an off by one error where you are starting your counter at 1 rather than 0.  I tested a few numbers and changing this seems to fix it just fine.  So change

```
int counter = 1;
```

to

```
int counter = 0;
```

Also, you must change your while loop conditional on the else block to be

```
while (numerator >= denominator) {...
```

in order to account for the case of when the divisor evenly divides the dividend.

Comment: when counter is set to zero the output I've been getting is:                
Enter two positive intergers for division:
25
5
25 / 5 = 4 with a remainder of 5. I played around with the counter to see if that was the issue but it wasn't, I'm probably making a mistake somewhere else.

Comment: wait scratch what I said before that you're correct, changing the counter fixes the case where numerator < denominator when the remainder is 0.  There must be a fault in the logic somewhere, I will review it over.

Comment: Ahh! I found the problem.  You need to change your conditional on the while loop in the else block to be while numerator >= denominator, in order to have the counter increment one last time on evenly divided pairs of numbers (where remainder = 0).  I have edited my answer to reflect these revelations.  It seems you are new to stack overflow like myself--please accept/upvote the answer if I have been helpful.

Comment: My man!!!, it worked, thank you so much, I upvoted your reply but it states I don't have enough rep for my upvote to be displayed. Thanks my guy.

Comment: Can you also accept my answer?  It's the green checkmark next to the upvote thing.  I believe you have the power and it'll really help my rep!  I'll be able to upvote your question afterwards too I believe.  edit: Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I saw few  errors in your code.
1. Redundant variable
2 why don`t you use modular operator ? 
3. you can remove a while loop too

```
public class Division {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input;
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter two positive intergers for division:\n");
        int numerator = input.nextInt();
        int numeratorprint = numerator;
        int denominator = input.nextInt();
        int quotient = 0;
        int remainder = 0;

        while ((numerator < 0) || (denominator < 0)) {
            System.out.print("Enter two positive intergers for division:\n");
            numerator = input.nextInt();
            denominator = input.nextInt();
        }
        if (numerator == 0) {
            System.out.print(numerator + "/" + denominator + " = " + numerator + " with a remainder of " + numerator);
        } else {
            if (denominator == 0) {
                System.out.print("This result is undefined (Cannot divide by Zero)");
            } else {
                if (denominator > numerator) {
                    System.out.print("Cannot do proper fractions");
                } else {
                    remainder = numerator % denominator;
                    quotient = ((numerator / denominator) - (remainder / denominator));

                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(numeratorprint + " / " + denominator + " = " + quotient + " with a remainder of " + remainder);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm supposed to do the operation without the use of either the modulo and the division operator.

Comment: ok then, but please check your counter returns the correct value.
print value should be counter - 1